# Complete list of nonforeign spelling exceptions involving the use of the letter "h" in Italian?

Tags: orthography, foreign-words, spelling

AFAIK, the following (possibly wrong!) points seem to summarize the use of the letter *h* in Italian:

- In Italian the letter *h* (commonly known as `acca` but also known as `acca muta`) never produces a sound of its own. According to Wikipedia, the letter *h* used to be pronounced as a *slightly aspirated h* in most if not all words in [Latin](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrittura_e_pronuncia_del_latino#Le_consonanti) (with possible exceptions made for words where the *h* is both preceded and followed by a vowel), but such pronunciation is lost in modern Italian.
- Whenever the letter *h* appears in a medial position within a word which is not a loanword (e.g. some extremely infrequent foreign words from French, German, etc...) it always affects the pronunciation of the letter immediately preceding it which must necessarily be the consonant *c* (which must appear as part of one the syllables `che` or `chi`) or the consonant *g* (which must appear as part of one the syllables `ghe` or `ghi`), with a few **exceptions** (e.g. I was able to find the words `ahó` and `ohimè`in the Treccani online dictionary).
- Whenever the letter *h* appears as the first letter of a word, the *h* does not affect the word's pronunciation. The only possibilities here are loanwords (several of which have been borrowed from English), plus four exceptions, all of which happen to be indicative mood present tense conjugated forms of the verb `avere` (to be), namely the words: `ho` (I have), `hai` (you have), `ha` (he/she/it has), and `hanno` (they have). **There seem to be no other exceptions in this case**.
- Whenever the letter *h* appears as the last letter of a word, the *h* may or may not have an effect on the pronunciation of preceding letter, which in this case must always be a vowel. examples are: `ah`, `òh`, `beh` (alternative spelling of the word `be’`), `boh`, and **possibly others**.

So, what I want to know is:

1. Is this list correct, or is something still wrong?
2. If correct, then what is the complete list of possible "**exceptions**" and "**possibly others**" as listed above?

Thanks!

Comment: Very easy: all of them, even foreign ones, unless you want to use the original pronunciation.

Comment: There are some latin words (which can hardly be classified as "loanwords" imho) still in use that start with "h": "habitat" and "herpes" come to mind. A dictionary probably lists them all in the "h" section.

Comment: Two very common words with a middle "h" are "ahi", used to express sorrow or pain, and "ehi", colloquially used to draw someone's attention in a somewhat casual way.

Answer (score 8):

The list is wrong about pronunciation. The rule is much simpler: you never pronounce the H, it's only used to tell a hard C/G (*call*, *gall*) from a soft C/G (*choke*, *joke*).

The graphic usage of H in words that are not loanwords is limited to *-che-*, *-chi-*, *-ghe-*, *-ghi-*, interjections (*ehi*, *ah* etc. and short forms used as interjections like *toh*, *beh* - also written as *to'*, *be'*) and these words: *ho*, *ha*, *hai*, *hanno* (verb *avere*, to avoid confusion with *o*, *a*, *ai* and *anno*). In all these cases it still has no sound.

Comment: But I thought the _h_ plays a role in difference between a hard g/c and a soft g/c only when the letters following the _h_ are either _e_ or _i_ (e.g., there couldn't be a word spelled like the English word _choke_ you mention). Are you saying this is wrong?

Comment: Yes but you cannot have _-cha-_, _-ghu-_ etc. BTW, I updated the answer because I had misunderstood the question, I though it was only about pronunciation.

Comment: OK, I made it clearer by specifying _-che-_, _-chi-_, _-ghe-_, _-ghi-_ as the only groups allowed.

Comment: Maybe you could make clearer the purely graphical nature in *ho hai ha hanno* with an example such as *me l'hai fatta*, where it's clear that the *h* doesn't hinder elision.

Answer (score 3):

From the Italian Orthography Wikipedia page (translated):

> ### Grapheme 〈h〉
>
> In Italian 〈h〉 is a so-called "silent" letter, i.e. without a phonological value (although in some cases it may indicate an aspirated sound `/h/`, similar to the [Florentine gorgue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuscan_gorgia)), whose main functions are diacritical and/or distinctive.
>
> Today's orthographically regulated uses are:
>
> 1. as a sign in the digraphs *ch-* and *gh-* indicating a hard *C* and *G* before *-e* and *-i*;
> 2. as a contrastive sign (of etymological origin from the lat. *hăbēre*) in the conjugations of the verb to *avere*:
>
>    - *ho*, *hai*, *ha* and *hanno*, to distinguish them from:
>    - *o* (conjunction), *ai* (articulated preposition), *a* (preposition), *anno* (noun).
> 3. in interjections, especially primary and monosyllabic. In this case there is no strict rule on its positioning, but there seem to be some nuanced customary uses:
>
>    - at the beginning, when it seems to want to suggest an aspirated sound, particularly in laughter: *ha ha* (`/ha ha/`), *he he* (`/hɛ hɛ/`), etc.
>    - after the first vowel in most cases: *ah*, *boh*, *eh* etc. but also *ahi*, *ehi*, *ohi*, etc., and in derivatives, *ahimè*, *ohimè*, etc.
>    - at the end, to indicate the exclamatory nuance of some grammatical particles: *mah*, (rare *cheh!*), substituting the final apostrophe in [truncations](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocope): *beh* (*be'*), *toh* (*to'*), etc.
>
> 〈h〉 is found in various contexts:
>
> - in some Italian surnames: *Dahò*, *Dehò*, *De Bartholomaies*, *De Thomasis*, *Matthey*, *Pamphili*, *Rahò*, *Rhodio*, *Tha*, *Thei*, *Theodoli*, *Thieghi*, *Thiella*, *Thiglia*, *Tholosano*, *Thomatis*, *Thorel*, *Thovez*;
> - in some Italian toponyms: *Dho*, *Mathi*, *Noha*, *Proh*, *Rho*, *Santhià*, *Tharros*, *Thiene*, *Thiesi*, *Thurio*, *Vho*;
> - in derivatives from foreign words: *hockeist*, *hobby*, etc., where usually the initial aspirated sound was lost with the Italianization of the pronunciation and therefore the *h* also can be omitted in a fully Italianized spelling.
> - in common Latinisms: *habitats*, *herpes*, *homo*, *humus*, etc. and Latin phrases: *ad hoc*, *ad honorem*, *horror vacui*, etc.

- [https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortografia_della_lingua_italiana#Grafema_〈h〉](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortografia_della_lingua_italiana#Grafema_%E2%8C%A9h%E2%8C%AA)

Additional toponyms containing *h*:

- [*Hano*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capovalle), [*Roghudi*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roghudi)

---

[image]

[*A Reference Grammar of Modern Italian*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RszKAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=aspirated+h), Martin Maiden, Cecilia Robustelli (P.5)

---

[image]

[*The Popular Educator: A complete Encyclopædia of Elementary, Advanced, and Technical Education. Volume III*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3TECAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA148&lpg=PA148&dq=lessons+in+italian+IV), Cassell, Petter and Galpin (Lessons in Italian - IV, P.148)

Comment: I'd like to know in what cases the *h* denotes an aspirated sound. The case of *ha ha* doesn't count, because it should be written *ah ah*.

Comment: @egreg The way I understood it, it is referring to the occasional use of *h* to denote the Tuscan pronunciation of some sentences. E.g. *Bevo la hoha hola holla hannuccia horta horta*

Comment: @DenisNardin: Credo ricordare che nel romanzo *Storie di animali e altri viventi* di Asor Rosa c'era qualcuno che parlava così.